# How do i add a transition effect to a link to the top side of the page? HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink, transition

I have an arrow at the bottom of my page that links to the top of the page and i want it to move slowly up. I think this would be added through transition or transform.

Comment: Hi Kayla, thanks for your question.  You are more likely to get good answers if you post some of your code, and describe how you have already tried to solve the problem, and what problems you have had.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth Scrolling is what you're looking for but it can't be done with just html or css. Here's a jquery script to accomplish it:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Now just make your arrow an anchor link with something like "#top" for the href value and add id="top" to an element at the top of your page.

The "1000" in the script is milliseconds during the scroll animation (so 1 second in this case). Adjust this if you need longer scrolling.